# PDO not available

Tags: codeigniter, pdo

I'm not a php developer, just started learning and migrating my php web site to code igniter. Previously I tried to deploy code on my production web site (paid hosting), and a class with PDO reference didn't work, so I backed out form that. My hosting company told me to change my plan to a more expensive plan. I don't want to do that but still I want to use PDO based code;
(From my CPanel I can see "PHP Version 5.2.17", however PDO doesn't work... I thought PDO was bundled with PHP 5...)

anyway
- Is this something that can be added to code igniter even if environment doesn't provide? as a library..etc?
- Or is it commonly available/provided if I change my hosting company to a free hosting company?

Thanks for your advises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO is built into CodeIgniter(system/database/drivers/pdo/); however, if your host does not support it, then it cannot be used.

As for free hosting that provides, PDO, you'll have to do your research on that one.

Comment: Thanks, I finished up migrating to code igniter and used 'mysql' driver (which was the only available driver with current hosting provider). I'll make sure to investigate database driver options before switching to another provider.